# Is there a way to return collection instead of entity in @Repository's @Query

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a query:

```
@Query(
    value = "select name, age, now() from received.scheme ;", 
    nativeQuery = true

)
public {???} selectData()
```

I cannot create or return an entity for such a scheme as there is no natural id in it, so is there a way to return something like List<Triple<String, Int, LocalDateTime>>?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52666044/1505146) help?

Comment: Is it helpfull https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23122846/query-returning-object-instead-of-entity?

Answer (score 0):

you can create another `class` with the required properties which you want to retrieve from the database and then you can return that class as `List<Class>`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you get the data from: `scheme`
So the Entity `SchemeEntity` should contains those three fields:

1. name
2. age
3. now (creationDate for example it depend on your logic)

Then your method should be like this:

```
@Query(value = "select name, age, now() from received.scheme ;", 
    nativeQuery = true
)
public List<SchemeEntity> selectData();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a PROJECTION entity which will have 3 attributes and must provide a parametrized constructor with those 3 attributes you want to fetch ,or you can still get them as a List<Object[]> and then hydrate your entity.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I've tried those things but what worked for me is using ctid as an @Id. Since I only needed some sort of a mock id, it worked fine.